# get rank of individual rows with data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, left-join, ranking-functions

Rank using a left join of another table data.

The app has tokens where the users can vote on. I want to be able to display the rank of each token in the app... The final objective is to create a MySQL view the query, but when trying to create the query I ran into some errors... I am unable to find what is wrong...

The query:

```
SELECT  a.id,a.name,a.symbol, a.logo, a.market_cap, a.price
      , a.launch_date, a.email, a.description, a.contract_bsc, a.contract_eth
      , a.contract_poly, a.link_website, a.link_telegram, a.link_twitter, a.promoted
      , a.status, a.date, COUNT(b.date) as 'votes'
      , rank() OVER ( partition by a.id order by 'votes' desc ) AS token_rank
FROM `tokens` a 
LEFT join votes b 
  on a.id=b.token_id;
```

This is the table structure:
[image]

The error that I am getting:
[image]

My Ultimate goal is to create a view where I can make search queries from it...

Comment: Normally you can't declare and use an alias in the same select; but this is mySQL....  I'd start by creating a derrived table which contains everything except the analytic function and then add in the analytic based on the aggregegration.  In addition; you have no group by for your aggregration; which just isn't wise.   IT would help to have sample dat and expected results. to help build from.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend just keeping it simple:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,a.symbol, a.logo  ...
   COUNT(*) as votes
FROM tokens a 
JOIN votes b
  ON a.id=b.token_id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Don't create this as a `VIEW`, there's no point. Using `VIEW`s as the basis for structures normally result in badly performing queries as they need to do unnecessary things.

Notes:

- Removed `LEFT JOIN` as I assume you didn't want to put tokens up without any votes. Correct if this isn't the case.
- `COUNT(b.date)` did you want to treat a NULL b.date as not being there. `*` is fine here.

Leave the putting of rank numbers as an application level construction. Decide if you want to count identical votes as an equal number.